# Thread wait state due to a cache miss

Tags: threads

I know that a thread in a "running" state is put in a "wait" state if the thread itself needs I/O operation. Now I'm asking if even a cache miss implies that a thread is put in a "wait" state.

Comment: The OS isn't aware of a cache miss. It cannot change the state of a thread in this case. The CPU isn't aware of software constructs like threads and such. There is no mechanism that allows the CPU to notify the OS of a cache miss. Doing so would be impossible.